# Why does pip install fail for the Python Watson Developer Cloud

Tags: macos, ibm-watson, watson

Here is the error I'm seeing. Is there something wrong in my install? Any help would be appreciated.

```
Installing collected packages: six, ipaddress, asn1crypto, enum34, pycparser, cffi, cryptography, pyOpenSSL, watson-developer-cloud
  Found existing installation: six 1.4.1
    DEPRECATION: Uninstalling a distutils installed project (six) has been deprecated and will be removed in a future version. This is due to the fact that uninstalling a distutils project will only partially uninstall the project.
    Uninstalling six-1.4.1:
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 342, in run
    prefix=options.prefix_path,
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 778, in install
    requirement.uninstall(auto_confirm=True)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 754, in uninstall
    paths_to_remove.remove(auto_confirm)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_uninstall.py", line 115, in remove
    renames(path, new_path)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/utils/init.py", line 267, in renames
    shutil.move(old, new)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 302, in move
    copy2(src, real_dst)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 131, in copy2
    copystat(src, dst)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 103, in copystat
    os.chflags(dst, st.st_flags)
OSError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/tmp/pip-ny7QGZ-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/six-1.4.1-py2.7.egg-info'
```

Answer (score 1):

Its a Mac OSX permission related problem. If you search for `OSError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted:` you will find possible resolutions, favourites being:

```
brew install python
```

or

```
pip install --ignore-installed six
```

or using virtualenv

Comment: I did the pip install --ignore-installed six command and it got passed this error but hit an error install pyOpenSSL. I've never used virtualenv before but can take a look. Seems like a lot of work to use a client library.

Comment: I took your advice and started using virtualenv and it was a good solution to this problem - thank you for the recommendation. One thing that came to mind is that I will look to reduce external dependencies on my library code since the probability of failure is cumulative.

Answer (score 1):

There is an entire discussion about this here : [Six issue when installing package](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/3165)

The solution that worked for me is :

```
sudo pip install watson-developer-cloud --upgrade --ignore-installed six
```